# initialize method with argument is not recognizing the argument

Tags: ruby, constructor, arguments

I am building a rather simple Module::Class with a initialize method.

```
module Encryption
  class Caesar

    def initalize(number)
      @caesar_number = number
    end
  end
end
```

when I run `Encryption::Caesar.new(2)` i get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
    from (irb):32:in `initialize'
    from (irb):32:in `new'
    from (irb):32
    from /Users/yedidyaweiner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>
```

If i run `Encryption::Caesar.new`, it successfully creates a new instance of the class.

Why is the error saying that it does not expect an argument when it is defined in the `initialize` method?

Comment: because you are creating a new instance of the Caesar class but not calling the initialize action. you'd need to change to Encryption::Caesar.initialize(2)

Comment: Initalize? Buy a 'i' :)

Comment: @smoggers: `Encryption::Caesar.initialize(2)` will throw a `private method 'initialize' called` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initalize` is misspelled; it should be `initialize`.

```
module Encryption
  class Caesar
    def initialize(number)
      @caesar_number = number
    end
  end
end

foo = Encryption::Caesar.new(2)
foo.inspect #=> #<Encryption::Caesar:0x1e05580 @caesar_number=2>
```